# Backup Solution for two /home directories

Tags: hard-drive, backup, ssd, home-directory, rsync

For years I have put my /home on an external hdd. It's now about 200 gig in size. I recently got my first SSD (250gigs). I want to put the OS (Ubuntu 16.04LTS) on the SSD and my question is with a /home on the SSD, how do I write /home to the internal HDD and then do my weekly backup to the external HDD so that I backup all the files/folders/directories?

Comment: You say that you've got a 250G SSD, but then you ask about writing a 200G /home to your internal HDD. It's unclear then what you've got internally and externally, and where you want 200G /home to be.

Comment: 3 devices here. Device #1 is the OS's hard disk drive (sda1), currently has Ubuntu 16.04 with / and /home (sda5) per usual install. Device #2 is external hard drive with backup of /home from #1. Device #3 is solid state drive. I want to switch #1 with #3, preserve all of /home on #1, and backup of /home on #3.

Comment: I must be dense, as it still makes no sense. Device #1 and #3 are internal? You want to boot to what device? Best if you could make a little ascii graphic that depicts a before and after idea of what you're thinking. Identify internal vs external drives, sizes, and what drive you want to boot to.

Comment: No idea how to ASCII. Sorry. Device #1is the equivalent of MS C: drive. It is the "main" boot device. It is the OS (Ubuntu) with 3 partitions: /,  /home, and swap. The external device is sdb when it is being used to backup. It is partitioned as but one partition as it has no operating system on it. It's sole purpose is backup storage of /home. I have a new ssd. I would switch the current C: with the ssd. Then, continue to make incremental backup of /home to the external hdd.

Comment: Oh, so really all that you're doing is upgrading an internal HDD with a new SSD, correct? And still continue to use the external drive as it is now, a backup of /home?

Comment: Yes, and thank you, Mr. Heynnema  for that simplification.

Comment: You'll end up with 2 drives connected to the system. An internal SSD with OS and /home, and an external HDD with a backup of /home (as it is now). The SSD is 250G. How big is the HDD that's coming out? How big is the external HDD?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61036/discussion-between-nn2013-and-heynnema).

Comment: Due to the used space on the 1TB internal HDD, there's no way to get it to fit on a 250G SSD replacement, and have room for anything else.